# Minimum Subset Difference code displays wrong output

Tags: python, subset-sum

My minimum subset difference code (Partition a set into two subsets such that the difference of subset sums is minimum) is displaying the wrong output, and I can't understand how. I have gone through everything, still can't understand it. Pls help me in solving this problem!!

**Example**

arr[] = {1, 2, 7}

Output: 4

Explanation: Subset1 = {1, 2}, sum of Subset1 = 3, Subset2 = {7}, sum of Subset2 = 7

so result will be 7-3 = 4

**here is my code**

```
import sys

def subset_sum(arr, n, S, dp):
    # If sum is 0, then answer is 1
    if(S==0):
        return 1

    # If sum is not 0 and set is empty,
    # then answer is 0
    if(n==0):
        return 0

    # If the value is not -1 it means it
    # already call the function
    # with the same value.
    # it will save our from the repetition.
    if(dp[n-1][S]!=-1):
        return dp[n-1][S]

    # if the value of a[n-1] is
    # greater than the sum.
    # we call for the next value
    if(S<arr[n-1]):
        dp[n-1][S] = subset_sum(arr, n-1, S, dp)

    else:
        # Here we do two calls because we
        # don't know which value is
        # full-fill our criteria
        # that's why we doing two calls
        dp[n-1][S] = subset_sum(arr, n-1, S, dp) or subset_sum(arr, n-1, S-arr[n-1], dp)
    return dp[n-1][S]

def minimum_subset_diff(arr, n):
    S = 0

    # Calculate sum of all elements
    for i in range(n):
        S += arr[i]
    
    # Create an 2d list to store
    # results of subproblems
    global dp
    dp = [[-1 for _ in range(S+1)] for _ in range(n+1)]

    # Fill the partition table
    # using memoization approach
    subset_sum(arr, n, S, dp)

    # Find the largest i such that dp[n][i]
    # is true where i loops from S (sum) t0 0
    diff = sys.maxsize
    for i in range(S):
       if  dp[n][i] == 1:
           
           # if S has partition of s1 and s2
           # then difference is s2-s1 => (S-s1)-s1 => S-2s1
           # hence, S-2*i is formed
           # and here we take absolute value
           if(abs(S-2*i) < diff):
               diff = abs(S-2*i)

    return diff

# Driver Code  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [1, 2, 7]
    n = len(arr)
    print(minimum_subset_diff(arr, n))
```

**output**

```
9223372036854775807
```

**expected output**

```
4
```

Comment: What, exactly, is this code supposed to be doing?  What result are you expecting?

Comment: to partition a set into two subsets such that the difference of subset sums is minimum.

Comment: What is the expected output for the above code?

Comment: "here is the result" Okay; *why is that result wrong?* What should the result be instead?

Comment: Some comments in your code would be nice, too.  I truly have no idea how you're trying to solve the problem, so no idea how to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What happens if you try testing parts of the code individually? If you call `subset_sum` with some specific values, do you get the result you expect? (Do you *know* what result to expect?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Comment: Can you explain why the output should be 1? What are the subsets you split [1,2,7] into?

Comment: @KrishnakanthAllika it will partition into [1,2] and [7] sets which will give the minimum differene of these two sets sum.

Comment: @KrishnakanthAllikaInput:  arr[] = {1, 2, 7} 
Output: 4
Explanation:
Subset1 = {1, 2}, sum of Subset1 = 3
Subset2 = {7}, sum of Subset2 = 7 and 7-3 = 4

Comment: @FrankYellin I have added all the comments and examples. I hope now it will be clear

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error.  I don't completely understand why you cache the value of `subset_sum(arr, n, S, dp)` in `dp[n-1, S]` rather than in `dp[n, S]`, which to me is more natural, but that's what you're doing.

But you forget about this off-by-one problem when examining the array later.  In your later code, you're looking at the wrong row.

When you re-write your code, look at the array `dp`.  Does it contain what you expect it to contain?  If you had looked, you would have noticed that the entire last row was -1, and you just return sys.max because the condition is never met.

I *highly* recommend you look at the documentation for @cache.  Let Python do this cacheing for you, rather doing it yourself.  These sorts of problems go away.

Comment: thank you, Frank, now I found the problem.